# I don't know how to remove the border outline of this text area

Tags: html, css

There is a blue outline around the outside of this textarea and I have already tried to do `outline:none;` in css.

here the code:

```css
#floatingTextarea {
  border: none;
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="form-floating container-fluid h-100 w-100">
  <textarea class="form-control text-center align-center" id="floatingTextarea" style="height:100vh;background-color:#dddddd;"></textarea>
  <label for="align-center" class="text-center"></label>`
```

[this is the blue outline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M3XLu.png)

I just want it to go away. I have looked at other posts about the same problem but I still cant seem to find an answer that works.

Comment: Outline none is working fine. There is no outline

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to say without knowing your actual code file.If possible please share it through codepen.
Till then I will share the solutions that worked for me which is  :

```
#floatingTextarea {
  border: none;
  box-shadow: none;
}
```

OR

```
#floatingTextarea {
  border: none;
  outline: none !important;
}
```

Comment: you are right. It is due to box shadow. Related bootstrap rule `.form-focus {...  box-shadow: 0 0 0 .25rem rgba(13,110,253,.25);}`.

Comment: Your suggestion FIXED IT. I used the first solution and it just worked to remove it! Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0):

Use your inspector to check weather outline: none; border: none; is applied to the element, make sure that the properties is no being stricken out. This may happens due to multiple reason

- when the css rule is written multiple times that is the css rule which is declared at top will be over written by the css rule with same written at the bottom
- when !important is used then the property-values without !important will be overwritten
- when multiple classes are used then the properties of first class will be overwritten by the latest class

The immediate solution for your problem is to use :

`#floatingTextarea { border: none !important; outline: none !important; }`

*Note that using !important should generally be avoided unless absolutely necessary because it is hard to maintain the code and debug it.*